# how to validate a modal with laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in a modal and I want to validate it with laravel, when I put the rules I get an error

> Method [validateRequire] does not exist.

, I think it's because of the modal,

When I do the same but in other forms, it's fine. 
I want the errors to come out in the modal

MODAL

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 b-r"><h3 class="m-t-none m-b">CREAR SLIDER</h3>

                            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST','route' => ['inicio.actualizarSler','id'], 'files' => true,'id'=>'form-editarslider']) !!}

                            <input type="hidden" id="idslider" name="idslider">
                            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Titulo</label> <input type="text" id="tituloEditar" name="tituloEditar" placeholder="Ingrese titulo" class="form-control"></div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Subtitulo</label> <input type="text" id="subtituloEditar" name="subtituloEditar" placeholder="Ingrese subtitulo" class="form-control"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="idMenu" name="idMenu" value="{{ $menu->idMenu  }}">

                            <div class="form-group"><label>URL</label> <input type="text" id="descripcionEditar" name="descripcionEditar" placeholder="Ingrese enlace" class="form-control"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {!! Form::file('rutaImagenSlider',['id'=>'file-rutaImagenSlider']) !!}

                                </div>
                            </div>

                           {!! Form::close() !!}

                            <div>
                                <button onclick="guardarSlider();" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" type="submit"><strong>REGISTRAR</strong></button>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

LARAVEL (REquesT)

```
class SliderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                 'titulo' => 'required',
                 'subtitulo' => 'required',
                 'descripcion' => 'required'

        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation rules will apply the same no matter what form its being used from front end as long as correct params are being send with a csrf token!

`require` should be `required`

However your issue its not modal but you have a typo on the rules last line.

```
return [

        'titulo' => 'required',
        'subtitulo' => 'required',
        'descripcion' => 'required'

  ];
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful if you had posted the controller code that handles the form request and how it integrates with the SliderRequest class.

Comment: This seems to be better suited as a comment, since it does not hold an answer to the question.

Comment: apparently, I cannot comment on his question without a 50pt  reputation